# How can I assert an instance of a ResourceCollection in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-7, laravel-testing

I am working with a feature test and it's returning data correctly; all things are coming back correctly; and I'm at the final portion of my test.

I am struggling to assert that I'm getting back a ResourceCollection:

```
$this->assertInstanceOf(ResourceCollection::class, $response);
```

Here is the portion of my test:

**MyFeature.php**

```
...

$http->assertStatus(200)
        ->assertJsonStructure([
            'data' => [
                '*' => [
                    'type', 'id', 'attributes' => [
                        'foo', 'bar', 'baz',
                    ],
                ],
            ],
            'links' => [
                'first', 'last', 'prev', 'next',
            ],
            'meta' => [
                'current_page', 'from', 'last_page', 'path', 'per_page', 'to', 'total',
            ],
        ]);

    // Everything is great up to this point...
    $this->assertInstanceOf(ResourceCollection::class, $response);
```

The error I get back is:

> Failed asserting that stdClass Object (...) is an instance of class "Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\ResourceCollection".

I'm not sure what I should be asserting in this case. I am getting back a resource collection, what should I be using instead? Thank you for any suggestions!

**EDIT**

Thank you @mare96! Your suggestion lead me to another approach that seemed to work. Which is *great* but I'm not too sure I really understand why...

Here's my full test (including my final assertion):

```
public function mytest() {
    $user = factory(User::class)->create();

    $foo = factory(Foo::class)->create();

    $http = $this->actingAs($user, 'api')
        ->postJson('api/v1/foo', $foo);

    $http->assertStatus(200)
        ->assertJsonStructure([
            'data' => [
                '*' => [
                    'type', 'id', 'attributes' => [
                        'foo', 'bar', 'baz'
                    ],
                ],
            ],
            'links' => [
                'first', 'last', 'prev', 'next',
            ],
            'meta' => [
                'current_page', 'from', 'last_page', 'path', 'per_page', 'to', 'total',
            ],
        ]);

    $this->assertInstanceOf(Collection::class, $http->getOriginalContent());
}
```

Comment: Did you tried `$this->assertInstanceOf(ResourceCollection::class, $response->getOriginalContent());`?

Comment: Thank you!! I didn't -- however your suggestion triggered another idea which ended up working. Which is GREAT, but not sure I understand exactly why... I updated my question hopefully you could explain a smidge so I could understand what I did?

Comment: You are welcome. It's because the content is what you need to test. Is that works? Do I need to type it as an answer? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I said in the comment above, your content will be the instance of Collection.

You can do it like that:

```
$this->assertInstanceOf(Collection::class, $http->getOriginalContent());
```

So, you can try to debug, to make it clearer, like this: Do `dd($http);` you should get an instance of `Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestResponse` not the same when you do `$http->dump();` right?

So you need to assert an instance of just content, not the whole response.

I hope at least I helped a little.

Comment: That makes complete sense. Thank you so much for taking the time to explain!